# Challenge: Access violation reading/executing location after successful compile

Tags: debugging, gcc, assembly

A challenge emerged from the Danish Center for Cyber Security a few weeks ago.
See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49702/programming-news-paper-puzzle/49757

A part of the challenge is to fix an Assembly code, load an .img file to process and then compile it. The file is called u5emu.asm.

A user called David J posted a cleaned-up version of the .asm code here: http://pastebin.com/TChuYF29

There's a minor bug where he wrote . instead of , on line 126, otherwise it looks good. What I did additionally was to change the getchar and putchar to _getchar and _putchar in the .asm code so the C lib would work. Also, I edited the U5_LE to _asm_main: since driver.c's main calls _asm_main.

I've gotten as far as to create an .exe by doing:

```
nasm -f win32 u5emu.asm
gcc -o u5emu u5emu.obj driver.c asm_io.obj
```

Which creates an executable file. I'm pretty sure that the program will ask me for an input (since there's a getchar) and it will then process the included file (a B64 encoded string which I've cleaned up and removed odd symbols like [, ; etc) and put out a clue for the next part of the challenge.

When I run the exe it crashes and I get two types of errors when I debug:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x546CD4A1 in u5emu.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

And

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in u5emu.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000
```

I've hit a dead end here, so hoping someone can assist me in how to crack this.

Comment: *Way* too many macros to be able to read the code. However, *"Access violation reading location 0x00000000."* means that you use a NULL pointer. Start looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to you question, but I can tell you what I did: I rewrote the small program into C (using a switch for the 32 opcodes). This makes it MUCH easier to add debug printout, etc. Hint #2: Remember to swap bytes, the emulated machine is big endian.

Comment: Hi Mogens. Thanks a lot for the hints. I will try to do that. Did you disassemble the asm to C to begin with and then rewrote it or did you finish it in asm and then make it into C? The asm file lacks a lot of code.. and what so you mean by "using a switch for the 32 opcodes"? Sadly my knowledge of assembly and C is very limited but I'm eager to learn it

Comment: I rewrote the code in C using the assembly listing as a template. It is not many instructions that need to be added. I used a switch construction in C instead of the computed goto.